Drywall over electrical wall outlet?
I had a recent flood and the drywall installers added new drywall to my basement.  At the electrical outlets they have covered the place where the screw holes are for the outlet cover. Do I simply cut out the drywall to expose the box? With a utility knife? There is drywall mud on the wires? Is this a problem? 

Good installers use a RotoZip like tool with a spinning spiral bit to cut close to the outside of the box border.

Whenever an electrical box is located near a joint in the drywall, mud in the box becomes a by product of taping and finishing. To get the wall smooth around the box, the mud man has to work the mud as though the box is not there. Because of that, a lot of mud gets in the boxes. Starting and stopping around the boxes always leaves a lot of trowel marks, and takes a lot more sanding to get it flat.

The job was done but left a bit sloppy.  Turn the power off the the outlet. Then it is ok to trim away a bit of drywall to get to the screw holes.
The mud on the wires isn't an issue other than covering the color for identification.  It usually chips off easily if you care to bother. You can clean the mud off the outlet too.  If there is mud in the sockets, it may be best to replace the outlet. ( they are relatively cheap.) Just remember to do any work with the power off.

It was a rushed job. Not the end of the world, but now you have to do the fine trimming. I wouldn't use a utility knife. A utility knife is typically used while installing sheetrock (sorry that's a trade name..."wallboard") to score one side and snap it with a firm push of your knee. In your case I'd use a wallboard knife to trim away enough wallboard to be able to seat the receptacles and screw them to the box. If you need, use an outlet cover as a guide so you don't trim away too much wallboard. Be careful not to insert the wallboard saw too far and nick wires as you're cutting. Just use the first 1/4 of the blade and use quick, short back and forth motion.
The joint compound on the wires is no big deal...as you manipulate them to wire the receptacles, most will fall off.

Wallboard saw is about the last tool I'd use to clean up around the box so receptacle can be installed. The teeth are far too coarse for that. A razor utility knife would be my tool of choice, it will easily trim away the small divot over the box mounting holes and any overhang at the sides that may interfere with the receptacle.
